# Google Maps app shows black screen after opening street view via URI Intent - Android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, google-street-view

Google map Streetview via intent shows a black loading screen.
Below is the code use for open Streetview Intent via URI,

```
 val gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("google.streetview:cbll=46.414382,10.013988")
 val mapIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri)
 mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps")
 startActivity(mapIntent)
```

Intent Code reference is taken from,
[Google Maps Intents for Android](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/android-intents#kotlin)

Seems like some bug in google map Android App,

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=streetview&p=1

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35830773

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/261816912

[image]

Comment: [Same Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74937891/google-maps-streetview-working-on-web-and-emulator-but-not-working-real-device) I think this problem is caused by Google Maps.

Comment: Did you tried on Emulator?

Comment: Yes, Try in Emulator but sams an issue there.