# Google Maps Streetview working on web and emulator. But not working real device black screen

Tags: android, google-maps, google-street-view

Street view that works on web and Android Emulator does not work on real device. I also tested Android 12, Android 9 and Android 13.

Google Maps version on emulator:
11.28.7

Google Maps version on device:
11.60.0703

The result is the same.

```
For example: 40.036716,42.171997
```

http://maps.google.com/maps?q=&layer=c&cbll=40.036716,42.171997

```
String destinationCoord = "40.036716,42.171997";
Uri uri = Uri.parse("google.streetview:cbll=" + destinationCoord);
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
mContext.startActivity(mapIntent);
```

[image]

Comment: Have you seen: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56870166/295004

Comment: @MorrisonChang Yes, this parameters didn't fix my issue. The problem still continues.